# QGIS 3.4.1 How to symbolize based upon characters of a 12-digit HUC code

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, vector-layer

I'm trying to group and then symbolize polygon shapefiles using HUC 12 codes.  Field name is "huc12"; field type is integer.  more specifically, I want to be able to group polygons according to the 8th digit by primary colors (red, blue, green, etc), then symbolize within the primary color range based upon the 12th digit (lighter to darker shades of red, blue, etc).  How can I achieve this?

Through fiverr I ordered a Python script, but cannot implement it, and I don't think this is the proper path forward.  I'd like to be able to code this symbology in through the field calculator if possible.

Edited to attempt to be more specific: In this instance, I'm seeking these watersheds primary-color coded into 4 groups based on the 8th number of a 12 digit number (code); then, within those primary groups, shade from lighter to darker colors based upon the 9-12th digits

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/haTyh.jpg]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Your Question title and body ask different questions (related, but different). Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact release of QGIS, the column name and data type (e.g. integer or varchar) in which the code resides, clarify the task (extract several digits or symbolize on different digits) and report what you have attempted, and where that failed to meet need.

Comment: You've edited the title, but you need to provide more detail on the rest of the question. Your question seems very answerable - if you provide the detail.

Comment: ok but i cant really see how to be more specific.  in this instance, im seeking these watersheds primary-color coded into 4 groups based on the 8th number of a 12 digit number (code); then, within those primary groups, shade from lighter to darker colors based upon the 9-12th digits.  ill paste this into the question, but please advise if you can help me be more specific

Comment: Consider adding a field or two fields (one for your four groups and one for 9-12 attribute values) for symbolizing use only.  Use the calculator to populate that field or fields.  If you don't want to add fields, you could add your layer three more times.  Each gets a different definition query and a main color.  Then categorize your symbology on the 9-12 digits.  How you do that depends on the values.  If you get something you like save to style files.

Comment: Some details that you could add into the question: (1) How does the 8th digit map to the 4 groups that you've mentioned? (2) How roughly do the 9-12th digits map to the shades (dark->light, light->dark, something else?) (3) Consider adding sample data extract to the question (upload to a site like Drive and share link). (4) Consider posting the script from fiverr, and what you asked for - noting that you have asked for a field calculator solution rather than Python - but the details may assist